# Implement (Override) method from object member of Parent in the child

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass, composition

Hello I am new to this.

I am adopting inheritance and composition in this app. But I want to implement a method of an object maybe a class member of Parent in child implementation. In the implementation below, I want `changeSpeed()` to be implemented differently for each Brain object. We decide the behavior of the Brains when we are in the Car. But brains belong the User as he is mentally ill.
What kind of solutions do I have in this case. Thank you for your responses.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Brain{
public:
Brain(std::string name):name(name){}
std::string getName(){
  return this->name;
}
void changeSpeed(){// change speed will be defined in Car
}
private:
std::string name;
};

class User{
  public:
  void addBrain(Brain b){
    brains_.push_back(b);
  }
  void showBrains(){
    for(auto &b:brains_){
      std::cout << b.getName() << std::endl;
    }
  }
  void apply(int index){
    brains_[index].changeSpeed();
  }
  private:
  std::vector<Brain> brains_;
};

class Car: public User{
  public:
  Car(){
    Brain one("one"); // +1 car speed
    Brain two("two"); // -1 car speed
    addBrain(one);
    addBrain(two);
  }

  void change(int index){
    this->apply(index);
    std::cout << "car speed " << getSpeed() << std::endl; 
  }

  int getSpeed(){
    return this->speed;
  }

  private:
  int speed=0;
};

int main() {
  Car car;
  car.showBrains();
  car.change(0);
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown how exactly you are planning to define these functions, so I'm going to make an educated guess and say you want to add an `std::function` member to `Brain` which is called by `changeSpeed`?

Comment: Since `Car` and `Brain` are unrelated classes, for `Car` to influence the behavior of `Brain::changeSpeed()`, you could have `Brain` hold a function pointer, or a `std::function`, which `Car` can then assign different functions to as needed. `Brain::changeSpeed()` can then call the currently assigned function.

Comment: Maybe just use classes that inherits "Brain", make them "friend" of car and override "changeSpeed" for each class. This is composition right ?